# Aquila X3 small firmware does not flash to board

Tags: marlin, firmware, mriscoc, aquila-x3

I'm using the [MRiscoCProUI](https://github.com/classicrocker883/MRiscoCProUI/) firmware on my Aquila X3 printer, but when I enable more features in the firmware, I'm unable to flash the printer.

I already tried several options and independently of the ones chosen, when the firmware gets to around 230 kB, I'm unable to flash it.

The printer has a [N32G455RE](https://www.nationstech.com/en/N32G455MCUs/) chip which has a 512 kB ROM, so I should be able to flash it, right?

Any ideas on what can be causing this?

**EDIT**: Apparently this is due to the bootloader not being able to handle firmware above 228KB.
Does this make any sense?
Is there any way that I can ensure the problem is really this?